# I would like a list of nodes by pair on which iterate through and not concatenated text nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, nlp, nodes

i work on an NLP project and i have to extract POS (parts of speech) in connection with object syntactic dependency.
Here is a piece of my xml file :

```
<titre>
<p type="titre">
<item><a>1</a><a>Antonio</a><a>Antonio</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>11</a><a>suj</a><a>11</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>2</a><a>Guterres</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>3</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>2</a><a>ponct</a><a>2</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>4</a><a>nouveau</a><a>nouveau</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>5</a><a>secrétaire</a><a>secrétaire</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>6</a><a>général</a><a>général</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>7</a><a>de</a><a>de</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>dep</a><a>5</a><a>dep</a></item>
<item><a>8</a><a>l'</a><a>le</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s</a><a>9</a><a>det</a><a>9</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>9</a><a>ONU</a><a>O.N.U.</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>7</a><a>prep</a><a>7</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>10</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>9</a><a>ponct</a><a>9</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>11</a><a>veut</a><a>vouloir</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P|p=3</a><a>0</a><a>root</a><a>0</a><a>root</a></item>
<item><a>12</a><a>faire</a><a>faire</a><a>VINF</a><a>VINF</a><a>t=W</a><a>11</a><a>obj</a><a>11</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>13</a><a>de</a><a>de</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>12</a><a>mod</a><a>12</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>14</a><a>2017</a><a>2017</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a></a><a>13</a><a>prep</a><a>13</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>15</a><a>"</a><a>"</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>16</a><a>une</a><a>une</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>17</a><a>det</a><a>17</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>17</a><a>année</a><a>année</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>12</a><a>obj</a><a>12</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>18</a><a>pour</a><a>pour</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>12</a><a>mod</a><a>12</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>19</a><a>la</a><a>la</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>20</a><a>det</a><a>20</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>20</a><a>paix</a><a>paix</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>g=f</a><a>18</a><a>prep</a><a>18</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>21</a><a>"</a><a>"</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>20</a><a>ponct</a><a>20</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>22</a><a>.</a><a>.</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>20</a><a>ponct</a><a>20</a><a>ponct</a></item>
</p>
<p type="titre">
```

the p node represent a sentence splitted in tokens (item nodes) with properties (the a nodes).
To put it simple, i need to extract item POS (a[4])(POS = parts of speech, is it a verb or a noun etc...) in syntactic dependency 'obj' (direct object). The syntactic dependency of an item is a[8]. In a[9], you have a number. It's the number of the governor of this obj. I need to grab the obj item and his governor.
For example, in the sentence : "i ate an apple", apple the obj and ate is the governor. Sometimes, it's more difficult.
In the file, item where a[1] = 12 is an object. You can see that because his a[8]=obj, his governor (a[9]=11), is the 11th item of my list. So i need to catch the obj item and the item where a[1]=12, the governor. In fact, i don't need the item as node, just his POS (a[4]). I'll have the following output in my example :
VINF V (or V VINF)

Here is my piece of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//p[@type='titre']"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="$pos">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p[@type='titre']">
        
        <xsl:if test="item[a[8] = 'obj']">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[a[8] = 'obj']">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="obj" select="a[1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="gouv" select="a[9]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$obj > $gouv">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::item[a[1] = $gouv]/a[4], '-', a[4])"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(a[4], '-', following-sibling::item[a[1] = $gouv]/a[4])"/>                    
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose> 
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I could manage to get all my sequences of POS obj+gov with the pos variable. I just concatenated the two POS in one string.

```
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//p[@type='titre']"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$pos">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But after, i have to do some post-process (sorting, counting...) and it's not possible at the moment. So the best i could get, is a list of a[4] nodes on which i could iterate with a for-each-group or get access to the first a[4] and the second one. Or even better, a list of node item by pair (obj and governor) Simply put, a list of pair elements a[4] obj and a[4] governor. I don't know if it's possible. I'm new to XSLT. Processing with strings is not a good option for me. My output is :

```
PROREL-V
V-VINF
VINF-NC
V-NC
CLO-VINF
V-P
VINF-NC
VPP-NC
V-VINF
VPP-NPP
V-NC
V-VINF
```

In practice, with my code, how to count occurrences of same POS obj POS governor (for that it's possible i think), how to determine which POS governor is the most frequent, get the POS frequency list by governor and the same with obj ? etc... I know that i work only with text nodes with this code, no copy, no copy-of... I'd prefer work differently.
In the best case, I would need a list of item nodes (obj + governor) as a pair, from which i could iterate through. Do you have an idea ? I read some things about copy-of, sequences, elements but i'm not be able to do that by myself. Or if you find an other way, easier, to make sorting and counting possible (with a for-each-group loop or any other way), I'm more than interrested. Optionally 2 parralel string lists, one for the POS obj and an other one for the governor. Keep in mind that it can be possible to have more than one obj-governor by sentence.

Comment: You continue to put us through your real input data and various problems at the same time. In general, I think it would be better if you could abstract away from the particular problem you need to solve and ask about smaller ones with simpler samples. As for forming "pairs", in XSLT 2 your main data structure is XML so you could create e.g. `<pair><xsl:copy-of select="a[1], a[9]"/></pair>` to get an intermediary structure where a `pair` element contains two `a` elements from your input.

Comment: Since 2017 we also have XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 or later, there additionally we have maps so you can do `<xsl:sequence select="map { 'obj' : a[4], 'governor' : a[9] }"/>` to "pair" two items as named properties in a map.

Comment: Thanks Martin. It's not easy when you come from C, C++ and Assembly. I try to learn the basics but it's pretty hard. The immutable variables are hard to manage too. Thanks you for the map. I can use any xslt version with any xslt processor. I work on Oxygen. I don't imagine if i had to do all those tasks on xslt 1.0